# brew: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh

As subject says, running

`brew doctor`

responds with following warnings:

`Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
...
Warning: Homebrew's bin was not found in your PATH.
....
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.`

However, when I echo PATH, it shows /usr/local/bin as being before /usr/bin

`/Users/bryce/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/bryce/bin:/Users/bryce/.rbenv/bin:/Users/bryce/.rbenv/shims:/Users/bryce/opt/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203:/Users/bryce/Development/tools/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/bryce/.homesick/repos/bzdots/custom/bin`

I'm running ZSH, iTerm on Mac OS X (Yosemite). Gut feeling is that these warnings aren't really important to me, but the OCD part of me wants to get rid of all warnings....

UPDATE:
Francisco below had the right idea. Turns out, I think it was an iTerm issue.  I found [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022582/osx-10-10-yosemite-beta-on-git-pull-git-sh-setup-no-such-file-or-directory) while researching another issue I was looking for. So, I just changed the default profile's command from "Login shell" to:

```
/bin/bash -c /bin/zsh
```

And its all happy.

Comment: You could sprinkle some debug output in `/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb` function `check_user_path_1` to check what it's thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that your `PATH` settings are dependent on whether your shell is running interactively or non-interactively?

Try running both:

```
zsh -i -c "echo \$PATH"
zsh -c "echo \$PATH"
```

and see if the output differs. Brew is likely reporting on your non-interactive path.